# Double loop: For loop within while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to solve this question:

> Write a for loop within a while loop that will count from 0 to 5, but when it reaches 3, it sets a game_over variable to True and breaks out of the loop. the while loop should continue to loop until game_over is True. the output should only be 0, 1, 2.

This is my code:

```
game_over = []
while game_over !=  True:
    for i in range(5):
       if i == 3:
          game_over = True
          break
       print(i)
```

The output is 0,1,2 but I am not quite sure that I am right or not. Appreciated your help.

Comment: Hi Cricket_007, my bad, I had : in the if statement.

Comment: initialise `game_over = False` instead of `game_over = []`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# your code goes here
game_over = False
while game_over !=  True :
    for i in range(5) :
        if (i == 3) :
            game_over = True
            break;
        print(i)
```

https://ideone.com/c8BAN8

Answer (score 0):

As long as you get the required output, it's "correct".

I would write like so

```
while not game_over:
    for i in range(5):
        print(i)
        if i >= 2:
            game_over = True 
            break
```

Comment: when I run your code, the output is 0,1,2,3. The required output is 0,1,2